# How to stop Sphinx to use Pygments for code blocks?

Tags: python-sphinx, pygments

pygments translates code blocks into very ugly, semantically invalid markup.

For example this rst

```
.. code block:: html
 <html>
  <head>... head of the document ...</head>
 </html>
```

will be translated into `pre` wrapped by two `div`s and will contain `span`s for each line:

```
<div class="highlight-html">
  <div class="highlight">
    <span class="x">&lt;html></span>
    <span class="x">&lt;head>... head of the document ...&lt;/head></span>
    <span class="x">&lt;/html></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to translate a code block into `code` wrapped by `pre` (as W3C recommends) like below?

```
<pre>
 <code>
   &lt;html>
    &lt;head>... head of the document ...&lt;/head>
   &lt;/html>
  </code>
</pre>
```

Comment: The Pygments `HTMLFormatter` class has a `wrapcode` option, but I don't think it does exactly what you want. https://pygments.org/docs/formatters/#HtmlFormatter.